# Angular - route not waiting for resolve

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `resolve` to determine whether an ID in the URL is actually valid (by an API call) before taking the user to that page.

However what I'm finding is for a brief second, it does actually go into the page specified in my route.

How do literally only go in, once the result has come back.

So my route code looks:

```
.when("/story/:id",
    {
      templateUrl: "views/story.html",
      controller: 'Story' ,
      controllerAs: 'story',
      resolve:{
        "check":function($location, usefulService, $route){
          var myPromise = usefulService.isValidQuestionID($route.current.pathParams.id);
          myPromise.then(function(result) {
            if (result == false){
              $location.path('/');
            }
          })
         }
        }
      }
  )
```

and then the actual API call method in my service:

```
self.isValidQuestionID = function(id) {
    return $http.get(API + '/isValidQuestionID', {
        headers:{
          idtocheck: id
        }
      })
      .then(function(res){
        return res.data.success;
      })
}
```

Any help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well hello again userMod2.

You need to return a rejected promise if you don't want the page to load. You can do that with this:

```
function ($location, usefulService, $route) {
    return usefulService.isValidQuestionID($route.current.pathParams.id)
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result == false) {
                $location.path('/');
                return $q.reject();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Haha - hi. i was going to comment on the previous post, however thought be easier here.

Comment: Awesome! That works. However I don't 100% understand, by doing a rejected promise, what stops it from loading the page as it did before?

Comment: Actually understand it now "create a deferred and then reject it immediately"